# NextJS fetch/stream file url and get 4mb limit error

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel

So I'm trying to fetch/stream a file url and I keep getting 4mb limit error, despite increasing limit size in api config https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares#custom-config. It seems as though this is an unresolved issue and github automatically closed it https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/33162.

nextjs version: `^12.2.0`

This is an api route `/api/getFile/[id].ts`, not a serverless function.

```js
import got from 'got'

export const config = {
  api: {
    responseLimit: '100mb',
    bodyParser: {
      sizeLimit: '100mb',
    },
  },
};

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method.toUpperCase() !== 'GET') return res.status(500).json({});

  const content_id = req.query.id;
  const file = await myDataBase.getFile(content_id)

  const { url, original_filename, original_file_url } = file.meta;

  try {
    got.stream(original_file_url).pipe(res);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send(null);
  }

};

export default handler;
```

This is the error i get when I'm fetching a file larger than 4mb, this only happens on production site (on vercel), when fetching large files on development i don't get this error

```
[GET] /api/getContentFile/f3c496a1-94e5-47d8-9630-44a679f2fe0e
02:01:38:93
[ERROR] [1658480502014] LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to post handler success response. Http response code: 413.
```

Comment: "The maximum payload size for the request body or the response body of a [Serverless Function](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/introduction) is **4.5 MB**." from [Vercel Limits](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview#serverless-function-payload-size-limit) documentation. API routes become isolated serverless functions in Vercel.

Comment: So there's no way to increase that **4.5 MB** limit

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post by next js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/api-routes-response-size-limit

> If you are not using Next.js in a serverless environment, and
> understand the performance implications of not using a CDN or
> dedicated media host, you can set this limit to false inside your API
> Route.
>
> ```js
> export const config = {
>   api: {
>     responseLimit: false,
>   },
> } 
>
> >
> ```
>
> responseLimit can also take the number of bytes or any string format
> supported by bytes, for example 1000, '500kb' or '3mb'. This value
> will be the maximum response size before a warning is displayed. The
> default value is 4MB.
>
> ```js
> > 
>  export const config = {
>   api: {
>     responseLimit: '8mb',
>   },
> } 
>
> >
> ```